# PLCameraControllerDelegate in IPhone SDK

Tags: iphone

I want to take photo continuosly with IPhone camera, I use code at:

[How can I take a photo frequently with iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325897/how-can-i-take-a-photo-frequently-with-iphone)

I have extracted .h files using Erica Sadun's PERL code, but when I try to run code above, by adding PLCameraController.h, I get

"cannot find protocol declaration for PLCameraControllerDelegate"

error,what should I do? Any more headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're willing to have your app require OS 3.1, there are now ways to do this that don't require undocumented headers, search the docs for the `takePicture` method.

if you want to keep going the way you're going, you could start with just using

```
@protocol PLCameraControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
// add any methods you actually use here

@end
```

to a header file somewhere.