# nil from Camera _createPreviewImage in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone

I am trying to apply Mike Chen's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325897/how-can-i-take-a-photo-frequently-with-iphone/1328176#1328176), using SDK 3.0. In delegate.m file I implement;

```
[viewController.view addSubview:[[objc_getClass("PLCameraController") sharedInstance] previewView]];
```

and in viewcontroller.m I implement:

```
CapturedImage = [[objc_getClass("PLCameraController") sharedInstance] _createPreviewImage];
```

but CapturedImage is always nil. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to check:

(1) Has `PLCameraController` been updated for iPhone 3.x? [This blog post suggest it has not](http://mobile-augmented-reality.blogspot.com/2009/05/iphoneusing-plcameracontroller.html).

(2) Instead of nesting all your calls Smalltalk style break them apart so you can see if your getting the objects you think you are:

```
WhateverClass *cameraController=[objc_getClass("PLCameraController") sharedInstance];
if (cameraController!=nil) {
    ImageClass *myImage=[cameraController _createPreviewImage];
}else {
    NSLog(@"camerController is nil");
}
```

Just remember that `PLCameraController` is a private framework that relies on a hidden Apple API. Even if you get it work, you most likely won't get it passed the App store review.