# always returns nil in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to apply Mike Chen's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325897/how-can-i-take-a-photo-frequently-with-iphone/1328176#1328176), using SDK 3.0. In delegate.m file I implement;

```
[viewController.view addSubview:[[objc_getClass("PLCameraController") sharedInstance] previewView]];
```

and in viewcontroller.m I implement:

```
PLCameraController *cam = [objc_getClass("PLCameraController") sharedInstance];
CapturedImage = [cam _createPreviewImage];
```

but 'cam' is always nil. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work when running in the simulator or on an iPod Touch. Are you running this on a physical iPhone with a camera?

Also, if you've dumped the headers correctly, you shouldn't be using the `objc_` runtime functions, but rather using the class names. Is the result of `objc_getClass("PLCameraController")` set to `nil`?

*On a side note: I hope you're not looking to publish your application through the App Store because this sort of private method calling is a great excuse for Apple to reject your application.*

Comment: I am running on a physical iPhone.
I have to use objc_getClass otherwise I get:

dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_PLCameraController
Referenced from: /private/var/stash/Applications.pwn/iPhoneCam.app/iPhoneCam
Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap

error

Answer (score 0):

To use PLCameraController, you'll need to include the PhotoLibray private framework. The simplest way to do that is drag drop an Image Picker Controller (UIImagePickerController) into your main nib.